# listar solo los anuncios que no se les ha enviado solicitud

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente duda,

Estamos trabajando en un sistema de avisos clasificados, los usuarios inician sesión y acceden a los avisos clasificados de la empresa, pueden enviar solicitudes a los anuncios en caso de estar interesados (por ejemplo en el caso de las vacantes laborales).

si el usuario decide enviar una solicitud, se crea un registro en la tabla solicitudes.

En la tabla anuncios están todos los atributos del los anuncios, titulo, descripción, estadoAnuncio, fecha de publicación...

En la tabla solicitudes por su parte esta un registro por cada solicitud que se halla enviado al anuncio, los campos de esta tabla son: idSolicitud, idAnuncio, idPersona, idEmpresa, estadoPersona, estadoEmpresa... El campo idPersona es FK con la tabla personas y el campo idEmpresa es FK con la tabla empresas.

Necesito listar únicamente los anuncios a los que el usuario NO halla enviado solicitud, es decir, si este usuario ya envió solicitud a un anuncio ese anuncio no aparecerá en la consulta.
.
Como podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías hacer una consulta mostrando los registros de la tabla Anuncios cuyo idAnuncio no se encuentre en la tabla Solicitudes asociado a la persona.

Por ejemplo para el idPersona "1" sería algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM Anuncios
WHERE idAnuncio NOT IN 
  (SELECT idAnuncio FROM Solicitudes WHERE idPersona=1);
```